# Testing my code against two Eclipse releases with Tycho

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

I am in need to test my code against two target platforms (which can be wrong to start with, but I would like to keep the focus on the issue): Kepler and Luna.

To do this, I defined two repositories in my parent project:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>kepler</id>
        <layout>p2</layout>
        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>luna</id>
        <layout>p2</layout>
        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Then I created two plugins, one for Kepler and one for Luna which declare two different dependencies (code is duplicated, but again this is a separate issue):

```
 // Luna
 Require-Bundle:
 org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts;bundle-version="1.3.100"

 // Kepler
 Require-Bundle:
 org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts;bundle-version="[1.3.0,1.3.100)"
```

Now, when I specify the adequate `tycho.target-platform`, through `-D` or settings.xml, and run the build with `mvn clean install`, one of these plugins always fails and the other one succeeds. Luna fails if I don't specify a Luna target, Kepler fails if I don't specify a Kepler target.

There must be a better way, I told myself, and I read about `target-platform-configuration` which I have configured with all the possible combinations of os/ws/arch.
But still it fails for one or the other. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you override your target platform configuration in the POM by using the deprecated `-Dtycho.target-platform` property. When that property is set, Tycho no longer uses the artifacts from the two p2 repositories that you have specified.

So, don't use this property (and also make sure that you don't set it your settings.xml) and your approach should work.

Answer (score 0):

My answer came right after checking my ~/.m2/settings.xml:

```
<profile>
  <id>tycho-kepler</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <tycho.targetPlatform>/usr/local/share/eclipse</tycho.targetPlatform>
  </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>tycho-luna</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <tycho.targetPlatform>/usr/local/share/eclipse-luna</tycho.targetPlatform>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Apparently these lines, even without having specified `-P` or the profile in the build, are added to the execution, something that I didn't now. Removing them solved the problem immediately.